# Why list.append() is not working at expected?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

To my knowledge, `list.append(item)` in Python adds an item to the end of the existing list.

Now, considering the following program:

```
numlist=[1,2,3]
vallist = ["a","b","c"]
db = []
card = ["number","value"]
for i in range(len(numlist)):
    card[0]=numlist[i]
    card[1]=vallist[i]
    db.append(card)
print(db)
```

I was expected the output `[[1, 'a'],[2, 'b'],[3, 'c']]`,

But, to my surprise, the output came as: `[[3, 'c'], [3, 'c'], [3, 'c']]`

I have tried, visualizing the aforementioned program using [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display):
[image: Python Tutor Output]

But I don't understand, why all 3 indices of the list indicate the last input of the list. What am I missing here? Also, how can I get my desired output using the list append method?

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: `append` doesn't make copies, it just inserts an alias. You keep appending the *same* `list` over and over, then mutating the `list` in place, but since you inserted nothing but aliases to the same `list`, all aliases show the effects of the final mutation.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @ShadowRanger How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @AmlanSahaKundu: Read the duplicate's answers. Many solutions. Short version is: Don't use the exact same `list` over and over, or copy it on `append`.